# Can not modify config.inc.php

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed password in phpmyadmin for root (there was no password actually) and now when I go to phpmyadmin, I receive this error:

MySQL said: Documentation

> Cannot connect: invalid settings.  mysqli_real_connect():
>   (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
>   password: NO)  phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and
>   the server rejected the connection. You should check the host,
>   username and password in your configuration and make sure that they
>   correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL
>   server.

I went to config.inc.php to add the password there, but I can't save modified config.inc.php, it shows that I don't have enough permissions to save it.

I went to google and searched for issues. I tried to change permission through terminal with 644, but it didn't work for me.

I even tried to reinstall XAMPP, but I still get the same error.

Now I have phpmyadmin on my computer, which doesn't work at all and I can't change it.

Please help me, how can I fix it?

Also I am using Mac and XAMPP.

Comment: Can you still access PHPMyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin/server_privileges.php?db=&viewing_mode=server or you can not just connect from your app?

Comment: I can't access PHPmyadmin

Comment: Make a screencast on how you changed the password, or how you tried to edit your config file. There's way too many underspecified points here. And this is barely a programming question, and more of a remote support request. Endless back and forth comments are off-scope.

Comment: Are you using xamp or wamp server?

Comment: I am using xampp

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXJs3.png
Here is screenshot

Comment: locate `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php` from the file explorer
- Right click and open as administrator
-Edit and save 

I suggest you stop the server before saving and restart after saving

Comment: But I am using mac... There is no "Open as administrator"

Comment: @DrueTrue you need to set your mysql password

Comment: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Open the Mac command shell.
- Use the `cd` command to set the directory to the location of your `config.inc.php` file.
- Type the following command:

  ```
  sudo nano config.inc.php
  ```

  You will be asked for your password; enter it. This puts the command into administrator mode.

  This will open the Nano text editor in the command window where you can edit the file. Find the password field (use `ctrl+w` if you need to search), edit it, and then use `ctrl+x` to save and exit. You should now be able to use phpMyAdmin again.

Answer (score 20):

Looks like when we install Xampp on mac, it tries to use it's own terminal, it won't work nano by default.

I have done below step which works for me.

1. Open terminal window (not mac default terminal please check attached image)
   [image]
2. Then Run `apt-get update` in the newly opened terminal. This will update some internal dependencies such as

   ```
      Get:1 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]       
      Get:3 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [475 kB]        
      Ign:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                             
      Get:4 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release [118 kB]                      
      Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release.gpg [2434 B]
      Get:6 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages [7090 kB]
      Get:7 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main Translation-en [210 kB]   
      Get:8 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main Translation-en [5388 kB]                                
      Fetched 13.4 MB in 54s (245 kB/s)                                                                                  
      Reading package lists... Done
   ```
3. Then run `apt-get install nano` this will install nano

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Suggested packages:
     spell
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     nano
   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
   Need to get 485 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 2092 kB of additional disk space will be used.
   Get:1 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 nano amd64 2.7.4-1 [485 kB]
   Fetched 485 kB in 3s (130 kB/s)
   perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
   perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
       LANGUAGE = (unset),
       LC_ALL = (unset),
       LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
       LANG = (unset)
       are supported and installed on your system.
   perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
   debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
   Selecting previously unselected package nano.
   (Reading database ... 13080 files and directories currently installed.)
   Preparing to unpack .../nano_2.7.4-1_amd64.deb ...
   Unpacking nano (2.7.4-1) ...
   Setting up nano (2.7.4-1) ..
   ```
4. CD to `cd ../opt/lampp/phpmyadmin`
5. Open/Edit `nano config.inc.php` and save.

This way it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, just follow step by step to fix this

1. open CMD with Xampp on macOs
2. apt-get update
3. apt-get install nano
4. nano /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php (and change password or everthing)
5. save with CTRL + O